# Hide mobile keyboard while keeping cursor in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

On mobile browsers, I want to do a different input system (like sticker) that I want to let user choose where exactly input, but hide the default mobile keyboard.

I've tried some way to hide the default mobile keyboard, e.g. `readonly` attribute or `blur` event, but losing text cursor.

Is there any way I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
input.blur();
input.focus();
```